# add personal funtion in setMethod in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, r-s4

I have and new S4 object with 4 Slots, one of them is a data.frame (g_table), so I want to add a parameters to setMethod to subset the data:

this is my actual code:

```
setGeneric('g_table', function(x) standardGeneric('g_table'))
setMethod('g_table', 'NewPackage', function(x) { x@g_table })

# assignment-methods: 
setGeneric("g_table<-", function(x, value) standardGeneric("g_table<-"))
setMethod("g_table<-", "NewPackage", function(x, value) {
  x@g_table <- value
  return(x)
})
```

and have no problem with it, just if I want to filter something in the data.frame (g_table) I need to do something like:

```
g_table(myObj) %>% filter(., gene %in% c("gene1", "gene2") )
```

and it filter the data, but I want to add the filter or subset option to g_table methods

first I tried to create a function

```
my_function <- function(obj, by){
    par <- substitute(by)
    dat <- obj@g_table
    gt <- subset(dat, eval(par, dat))
    return(gt)
}
```

it works like:

my_function(myObj, gene %in% c("gene1", "gene2") )

so I tried to replicate it in setMethod, something like:

```
setGeneric('g_table', function(x, by=NULL) standardGeneric('g_table'))

setMethod('g_table', 'NewPackage', function(x, by=NULL) { 

  if(!is.null(by)){
    par <- substitute(by)
    dat <- x@g_table
    gt <- subset(dat, eval(par, dat))
  }  
  if(is.null(by)){
        gt <- x@g_table 
  }
  return(gt)
})
```

This is the error:

```
g_table(MyObj, gene %in% c("gene1", "gene1") )
 Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function '%in%': object 'gene' not found
```

any way to fix or do it ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't appear to have anything to do with S4's setMethod specifically. You can simplify this to

```
foo <- function(x, by=NULL) { 
  if(!is.null(by)){
    par <- substitute(by)
    subset(x, eval(par, x))
  } else {
    x
  }
}

dd <- data.frame(gene=c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene1"), val=1:4)

foo(dd, gene %in% c("gene1", "gene2"))
```

which gives the same error. The problem is when you do `is.null(by)` you are evaluating the `by` parameter. The collapses the promise and you can no longer use `substitute` on that value.

It's safer to use `missing()` rather than checking for NULL

```
foo <- function(x, by) { 
  if(!missing(by)){
    par <- substitute(by)
    subset(x, eval(par, x))
  } else {
    x
  }
}

foo(dd, gene %in% c("gene1", "gene2"))
foo(dd)
```

If you really needed to check for NULL, you could do something like

```
foo <- function(x, by=NULL) { 
  by <- substitute(by)
  if(length(by)>0 && as.list(by)[[1]] != as.symbol("NULL")){
    subset(x, eval(by, x))
  } else {
    x
  }
}

foo(dd, gene %in% c("gene1", "gene2"))
foo(dd)
foo(dd, NULL)
```